# AS3: Keyboard Input won't work on Internet Explorer

Tags: actionscript-3, internet-explorer, keyboard-events

I've got a flash movie which imports an external SWF.
I have some interaction inside the external SWF (WASD to move the star) AND in the container (O to change circle color).
Everything works on Chrome and Firefox, but not on Internet Explorer and this is giving me a headache.
Here is the test: http://clients.adrime.com/files/campaigns2/9785452187/38177/default.htm
Here the code for the interaction of the CONTAINER:

```
stage.focus = stage;
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onoff);
function onoff(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(e.keyCode == 79) //O
        bulb.gotoAndStop(bulb.currentFrame == 1 ? 2 : 1);
}
```

Here the one of the EXTERNAL SWF:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, added);

function added(e:Event):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, tastiera);
}

function tastiera(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
        st.x -= 5;
    else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
        st.x += 5;
    else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
        st.y -= 5;
    else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
        st.y += 5;
}
```

What is that I'm missing?

Comment: Hi, I receive a warning in flash.log:
Warning: Reference to undeclared variable, '_init'. Is it related with your code? Also there is a lot of Security Sandbox violations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operating system and the web browser will process keyboard events before Adobe Flash Player or AIR.

For security reasons **FLASH never is auto focus** - otherwise stealing keyboard input would be a snap.

> A Flash movie embedded in an HTML page does not receive key events
>   when the page first loads in a Web browser.

There is a [official Javascript solution](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15586.html). You can also use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed your flash content.

Comment: I thought problem not an autofocus issue because after click on stage it won't work why?

Comment: I figured out that the problem was in the environment page that was blocking all the inputs to my movie. I talked to the owner of the page and he fixed it. Thank you the same!